# Web audio oscillator extremely loud?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Is it just me or does the oscillator sound crazy loud even at 0.5 gain? I cant increase my computers volume more than 5%.

Now the volume seems "normalized" when I set the gain to 0.001 but that cant be right? I would appreciate some insight for controlling the volume of the oscillator.

```
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();

var oscillatorNode = audioCtx.createOscillator();
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();

oscillatorNode.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

oscillatorNode.type = 'sine';
oscillatorNode.frequency.value = 500;
gainNode.gain.value = 0.5;

oscillatorNode.start();
```

Comment: On one machine here the oscillator volume is only reduced when using negative gain values `-1.0 .. 0.0` (which normaly is used for phase inversion). Someone else seen this behavior? Driver issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro any extreme loudness. With `gainNode.gain.value` at 1.0, I get a clean sine which is not overly loud. Raising the gain over 1 makes the sine wave clip, as expected. Lowering the gain to 0.001 makes the wave practically inaudible.

There's probably something else going on with your machine, if it's "crazy loud".

Comment: At gain 1 you cant really raise the volume to 50% or can you? How far can you raise your computers volume without making yours ears bleed?

Comment: Depends on how loud I have my speakers on. ;) I can raise it to 100% just fine at present. I think @lenilsondc is on the right track with the audio enhancement stuff.

Comment: I think that is a problem though. Since im creating a online synth, people could get hearing damage if they got a gaming computer or something.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce it by having "Loudness Equalization" enabled on my speakers enhancements (I'm using Windows 10). You probably have an audio effect being applied to your speakers' out.

The solution: disable all audio enhancements/effects from your speakers (specially Loudness Equalization that mess up with the amplitudes hence the volume).

Audio enhancements can also be found on headset drivers trying to optimize users experience of the headset.

Comment: Ok I deactivated all sound effects in "sound ->device properties. Lets see if it gets better.

Comment: Ok it doesnt work. I got dolby digital on. I will see what happens if a deactivate it.

Comment: Apparently it's not an issue with webaudio itself but with your machine and/or setup. Some devices simply increase loudness, some drivers simply increase loudness, or your audio card is meant to run a DJ party or something. Does it happen only with webaudio or if you play something from a different software it happens too?

Comment: good question. I havent tried it yet but videos, music and even https://midi.city/ works great.

Comment: Pure sine waves probably mess up the loudness equalization.  Videos or music probably has audio content spread across a large range of frequencies so the loudness equalization probably works better.